# How could I add or append to my cucumber Table?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In cucumber, one of the best feature is the Table data passing. However if I want to add additional data to it, or create a Table data in my step_definitions, how could I do that? What type is Table (hash? map? list? array?)?

To illustrate, below is one of my step, accepting a table data from the feature, and pass along to a function. I like to append some data to it. How could I do that?

```
Then(/^posted JSON should have the below attributes$/) do |table|
  ## Here I want to append some data to my table. How to do it?
  posted_json_attribute_table_check table
end
```

Then I have a function that use it to compare with a read JSON.

```
def posted_json_attribute_table_check(table)
  json = JSON.parse $post_result.lines.first 

  data = table.raw
  data.each do |entry|
    status = entry[0]
    value = entry[1]
    expect(json[status].to_s).to eq(value)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The table object is of type Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable and can be found here. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby-core/blob/master/lib/cucumber/core/ast/data_table.rb

```
# Creates a new instance. +raw+ should be an Array of Array of String
# or an Array of Hash
# You don't typically create your own DataTable objects - Cucumber will do
# it internally and pass them to your Step Definitions.
#
def initialize(raw, location)
  raw = ensure_array_of_array(rubify(raw))
  verify_rows_are_same_length(raw)
  @raw = raw.freeze
  @location = location
end
```